# Disable VBA script creation or modification in MS Office apps

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-office

as the title suggests.  Allow execution of previously created scripts but disallow creation of new ones or modification of existing script.  Blocking of VB doesn't work since the editor spawns as the parent process.

Answer (score 0):

You can always protect the existing VBA project:

From the VBA Editor, select Tools > VBA project properties > Security > Lock project for viewing, enter a password and save.

Additionally, Modern versions of MS Access provide a method to save your database as a compiled executable format (*.accde) which you can then publish to your users without fear of them modifying or inserting VBA code.